# GridView paging inside an UpdatePanel or PlaceHolder components

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I'm new to ASP.NET.

Im developing ASP.NET C# web form which creating `GridView` components dynamically and filling them using the data received from my webservice.

I'm creating these `GridView` components programmatically in server-side (cs file)- it has to be flexible - 1 GridView and sometimes 10 `GridView` components.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to add pagination - whenever the user clicks the "next" page, the whole page is getting refreshed because of a postBack and I'm loosing all my data and the page returns Blank/Empty.

I used `PlaceHolder` to hold the `GridView` components, while searching for a solution, I found UpdatePanel as a better alternative - as far as I understand the page can be partially refreshed - which means that only the `UpdatePanel` has to be refreshed...but it doesn't work.

The following code sample is my TEST, the UpdatePanel is the only component initiated in the client side (`.aspx` page), the rest initiated programmatically in `.cs` .

how can I solve the issue described above?

Why does the whole page is getting refreshed and I'm loosing my data? 
can you recommend another way? can provide me with any code sample?

If I'm not rebuilding the `GridView`, it doesn't work...

Here is my `Default.aspx.cs`

```
public partial class TestAjaxForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable table;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            bindGridView();
    }

    public void bindGridView()
    {

        GridView gridView1 = new GridView();
        gridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        gridView1.PageSize = 2;
        gridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        gridView1.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.Numeric;
        gridView1.PagerSettings.Position = PagerPosition.Bottom;
        gridView1.PagerSettings.PageButtonCount = 10;
        gridView1.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(this.GridView1_PageIndexChanging);

        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        table.Columns.Add("LastName");

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["FirstName"] = "John";
        row["LastName"] = "Johnoson";
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        row = table.NewRow();
        row["FirstName"] = "Johnny";
        row["LastName"] = "Marley";
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        row = table.NewRow();
        row["FirstName"] = "Kate";
        row["LastName"] = "Li";
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        panel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(gridView1);

        gridView1.DataSource = table;
        gridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView1 = (GridView)sender;
        gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridView1.DataSource = table;
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a custom GridView approach to work, you have to recreate and rebind the grid on every page load... that's the problem with dynamic Grids...  Dynamic controls don't retain their viewstate, but if you added the grid and dynamically generated the columns, that would work easier for you (because I think it may dynamically remember the columns, or you can set AutoGenerateColumns to true, and it brings in your data row column names).

HTH

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks. But as I wrote above, I'm creating the gridView programmatically. I understand that there is a way to handle the postbacks and refresh only the updatepanel and not the whole page...
I think that this is one of the main reasons for UpdatePanel.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you have to recreate the Grid on every page load, and that is the issue...

Comment: Using a GridView staticly on the page with AutoGenerateColumns was an alternative if its possible to modify the page to use that approach... but only you know the reqmts.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you, Im not sure if creating the gridview in every pageload is the right way, logically, Im sure that there is another way to refresh only part of the page.

Comment: Creating the gridview dynamically can be tricky, which was my second suggestion of including the control on the page, but changing it's values.  That way, ViewState would retain some of not all of the changes and you would only need to worry about the setup particulars...

Answer (score 0):

You should create your GridView and add it to the control tree in the PreInit or Init event handler so that they have a chance to properly bind to ViewState, and it should be done whether or not there's a postback: if you don't add them in a postback, they obviously won't be there to display anything.

DataBinding can happen later in the page life cycle.

Paging only seems to work if you also use an ObjectDataSource; I've never been able to get it to work with a GridView by itself.

Comment: Thank you, but paging is important for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I was trying to let you know how to make paging work: use an ObjectDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do is have the gridview declared in the aspx page inside the place holder, while the place holder is also contained inside the update panel.

For what I can see, John is not doing anything that can't be declared in the markup itself so that shouldn't be a problem. If for some reason the gridview should not be displayed on the screen, it suffices to set the Visible property of the placeholder to false.

As far as paging is concerned, as RickNz correctly points out, it will only retain the state if you bind the gridview to either a LinqDatasource, SqlDatasource or ObjectDatasource but if you bind it to custom business objects, what you need to do is save the data in Session and rebind it again on PageIndexChanged.

In pseudo code, would be sometging like this.

```
Page_load
{
     If (!IsPostBack)
     Binddata();
 }

 private void Binddata()
 {
     var data = Getdata();
     Gridview1.DataSource= data;
     Gridview.DataBind();
     Session["data"]=data; // cache the data 
  }

 protected void Gridview1_indexchanged(object sender, GridviewPageEventArgs e)
 {
      var data= Session["data"];
      Gridview1. DataSource=data;
      Gridview1.DataBind();
      GridView1.PageIndex=e.NewPageIndex;
  }
```